# What formula is used in "escalc" (R - package metafor) to calculate yi, vi, sei, and confidence intervals?

Tags: r, metafor

I am performing a meta-analysis using standardized mean difference as measure of effect size. For each study, I have sample sizes, standard deviations and mean values of i) control group and ii) treatment group. I then used the function "escalc" from the package metafor, to calculate effect size (yi), variance (vi) standard error estimates and confidence intervals, with the following script:

```
SR_meta <- escalc(measure="SMD", m2i=cn_mean, sd2i=cn_sd, n2i=cn_n,
               m1i=treat_mean, sd1i=treat_sd, n1i=treat_n, data=SR)
```

I have then tried to calculate the values "by hand" (in R) and I get slightly different results. So I was wondering if anyone could tell me what formula is used in "escalc" as I have the feeling we are using different corrections, or possibly different formulas somewhere.
Below I'm attaching a) how I've calculated the values by hand, and b) examples of both outputs to show the differences.

a)

```
SR2$sd_pooled<-sqrt(((SR2$treat_n-1)*SR2$treat_sd^2 + (SR2$cn_n1)*SR2$cn_sd^2)/(SR2$treat_n+SR2$treat_n-2))

SR2$smd<-(SR2$treat_mean-SR2$cn_mean)/SR2$sdi

SR2$smd_j<-SR2$smd* (1-(3/(4*(SR2$cn_n+SR2$treat_n-2)-1))) #Hedge's adjustment

SR2$Vd<-((SR2$cn_n+SR2$treat_n)/(SR2$cn_n*SR2$treat_n)+((SR2$smd^2)/(2*(SR2$cn_n+SR2$treat_n))))

SR2$sei<-sqrt(SR2$Vd)
```

b) with escalc I obtain values like

```
yi= 1.478805, 2.88312, 2.121931
vi= 0.4655, 1.634453, 1.19089
sei= 0.682276, 1.278457, 1.091279
```

while manually I obtain:

```
yi= 1.479336, 3.726113, 2.74361
vi= 0.440349, 1.81426, 1.288287
sei= 0.663588, 1.346945, 1.135027
```

So I'm wondering where the mistakes happens and what formula escalc uses?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: As far as R packages go, the commenting of [the source](https://github.com/cran/metafor/blob/master/R/escalc.r) of `metafor::escalc` is pretty good. Maybe check that out.